CosmosDB scale down to less than 10,000 RU/s, how long does it take?
I know it takes 4-6 hours to scale up to more than 10,000 RU/s.
I want to know how long it takes to scale down to less than 10,000 RU/s.


This is instant.
The "4 to 6" hours estimate when scaling up is because each physical partition can only support up to 10,000 RU/S.
In your case you only have a single partition and it will have to perform potentially multiple rounds of binary partition splitting until it has enough partitions such that 10,000 * new partition count is greater than or equal to your desired RU.
But time taken to scale down is not the only consideration here.
If you were to scale up to 1,000,000 RU and get 100 physical partitions as a result you could encounter at least three undesirable effects though to consider.

Queries without the partition key (AKA "Cross Partition" queries) will now have to fan out to 100 physical partitions - not just the single partition any more!
You would no longer be able to scale back down below 10,000 RU in this example due to the "Highest RU/s ever provisioned on the container / 100" rule
If you were to scale back down to 10,000 your RU per physical partition budget would now be only 100 RU/S (as you have 100 physical partitions). This could cause problems for many workloads if you encounter throttling in some partitions whilst others have unused capacity - which is why partition merge exists.

From the screenshot you posted it looks like you are just going up to 20K though so this should just require a single partition split and having 2 partitions after the split is much less of an issue than 100!
